# R: data.table count rows on specific columns > 0

Tags: r, data.table, countif

I am try to do a countif function like in excel. I want to countif a select set of columns in a row that are > 0.

I am using the `data.table` package to filter and count my data.

my data.table is `DT` with over 5000 rows of data, with 17 columns. Here is a quick snapshot of what it looks like. Weeks are from weeks 1-12.

```
Area     Park   Number   Code  Text    Week1 Week2 Week3 Week4 Week5
Central  Bear   80458    FM50  Safety   1     0     5     20     0
```

What I am looking for: (count weeks >0)

```
 Area     Park   Number   Code  Text    Week1  Week2  Week3  Week4  Week5 RowCount
Central  Bear   80458    FM50  Safety     1      0      5      20     0       3
```

What I was trying to do was:

```
DT <- DT[, RowCount := rowSums(DT[, c(-1, -2, -3, -4, -5)] >0) ]
```

This works for summing the rows, it removes the columns I do not want to count, but when I looked into the other 5000 rows it was summing all >0, not counting all >0.

In essence what I want to do is like excel `countIf` function

Any help is appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a way using `rowSums`:

```
dt <- data.table(W1 = sample(0:2, 3, rep = T),
                 W2 = sample(0:2, 3, rep = T),
                 W3 = sample(0:2, 3, rep = T))

dt[, Count := rowSums(.SD > 0), .SDcols = 1:3]

   W1 W2 W3 Count
1:  0  0  0     0
2:  2  1  1     3
3:  0  2  1     2
```

You just have to adjust for the columns to work on in `.SDcols`.

Comment: The trick behind this: `.SD > 0` creates a TRUE/(FALSE matrix and in R `TRUE` is 1 and `FALSE` is 0, so you can simply use `rowSums` to count "1"s per row...

Comment: Thanks this did the trick I was looking for Thanks for the help.